# Helm - Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have an application "A" which requires postgres database. Once I deploy the helm chart it deploys the child dependent chart postgres.

```
helm install application_A -n mynamspace ./applicationA-0.1.0.tgz
```

Now I have another application "B" which also requires postgres database. I wish to deploy the application B in the same namespace but it should not deploy new postgres POD as it is already available from Application A's deployment.

```
helm install application_B -n mynamspace ./applicationB-0.1.0.tgz
```

It fails with the following error -

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists
```

I want helm to recognize that the dependency of application 'B' is already deployed with the desired version and hence it should automatically avoid deploying the dependent chart.

I am aware of conditional deployment of subchart. It requires me to find out what is already available using shell script to toggle the condition while deploying Application B.

Is there any way in helm to automatically avoid deploying subchart if it is already deployed?

helm version - v3.8.0

Comment: In normal operation, you _do_ want each application to install its own database container, and objects are typically named something like `{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}` which would cause the two database StatefulSets to not conflict.  What's the specific subchart involved here?

Comment: I was trying with postgres subchart - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql

I dont want to start two postgres containers, rather one container and act as a shared server.  Each microservice can refer to their own schema.  Managing multiple database servers is an overhead.  This is applicable to other shared resources like Kafka which I do not want to deploy with each application.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there should not be any relation between two helm release installations. Each helm installation would always try to install their components. Here, it could be failing because of the hardcoded name of resource. Just for your use case, you can use helm in-built `lookup` function to see if resource exist do not create.
link:
`https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function`